# How to use Robo3T to connect mongodb server running as a docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I have a mongodb running as a docker container which created by docker-compose.
Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
verion:'3.7'
services:
    mongo_env:
        image: mongo:4.2.1-bionic
        ports: 
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes: 
            - $PWD/DBVOL/mongo/data:/data/db:rw
        environment: 
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <rootuser>
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <mypassword>
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: <mydatabase>
```

I want to connect mongodb from outside using Robo 3T,But It always tell me that 'Failed to load database'.Here is my Robo 3T config:
[image]

Please Help me It's emergency!

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure it started successfull? Your Docker Compose has a typo in "version:3.7".
correct version:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
mongo_env:
    image: mongo:4.2.1-bionic
    ports: 
        - "27017:27017"
    volumes: 
        - $PWD/DBVOL/mongo/data:/data/db:rw
    environment: 
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <rootuser>
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <mypassword>
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: <mydatabase>
```

Please check after starting  if the container is running with

> docker ps

Comment: Try to use  image:mongo:4.0